# How to compile SWIG via windows

Tags: c++, c, swig

I've downloaded swigwin, sigwin for windows, and have been checking examples. However, most examples have to compile like this: swig -example.i. I tried doing this over the cmd prompt but it does not work. Can you please teach me how I can do this on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose a language.  To create a Python extension wrapper for C:

```
swig -python example.i
```

for C++:

```
swig -python -c++ example.i
```

See `swig -help`.

You may also need to add `swig` to your path.  Something like:

```
path c:\swigwin-2.0.0;%path%
```

Or add it through Control Panel, System, Advanced, Environment Variables (on WinXP).

Comment: thanks! regarding adding via control panel, do i add under user or system variables? and lastly how do i accept an answer

Comment: System is global for all users.  If you are the only user of your system it doesn't matter.

Should be a check box near my answer to accept. :)

Comment: thanks! quick question though, do i generate the interface (file.i) files or the swig does that?

Comment: You create the .i file, although swig has a library of pre-written .i files as well that you can `%include`.

Comment: hello there! i hope you can still spare me a few minutes of your time. ive generated the file_wrap.c and file.py files. next step is to compile. the command they say to use is "gcc -c example.c example_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.2 -I/usr/lib/python2.2" . i understand that gcc is a compiler(?). ive checked around the net and saw that dev c++ uses mingw so i do "mingw -c example.c example_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.2 -I/usr/lib/python2.2". however it failed. im sorry im really a noob when it comes to things like this

Comment: You should ask this as another question on SO.  Since you are using swigwin and those paths are Linux paths, what you want is the paths like C:\Python26\include and C:\Python26\Libs (depending on the version of Python installed and where you installed it).

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you're asking about compilation, I'll like to add two things (knowing there already is an excepted answer):

- I've come here from Google looking for how to *compile* on Windows, and the `swig` command does not compile anything. It just translates given input to (in my case) `.java` and a `*_wrap.c` files, which is *uncompiled* source code
- in order to compile - in terms of using the `gcc` or `g++` commands from [SWIG's tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) -  you have to install a compiler. The [Windows examples](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Windows.html) describes three options: Visual Studio, Cygwin or MinGW (download [here](http://www.mingw.org/download.shtml)). To compile the `.java` files from above just use `javac`; for details see the according "Building a  module"-section in the [tutorials](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html).